Converting a string that is 2 digits to Base64
For my specific problem I am having the user enter into a text field a two digit number pin, which converts to hex I think? somehow and then base64. I want for example the hex of 01 to output the base64 equivalent AQ==, and 02 to output Ag==, up to a max of 99 which is mQ==.
First of all is this okay? to have two digits [0-9], [0-9]. There shouldn't be an issue correct and it will always have a unique base64 value?
Second, I can't get it to properly work
For input "01", I am getting MDE=. Which is too many bytes and incorrect. I need only 1 byte values. For the input of "0" I get MA== which is the correct number of bytes but only using one digit.
I know I am doing something fundamentally wrong and all encoding/decoding solutions I've found only confuse me more. I think it may have to do with the int actually being a string, but I cannot pass an Int to .data method. Asking for advice from someone much smarter than I, Here is some of my swift code tyia
 .onChange(of: channelKey, perform: { value in
        // Limit input to two digits because that is what we want               
        let totalBytes = value.utf8.count
        if totalBytes > 2 {
        if let maxBytesString = value.truncated(to: 2) {
        channelKey = maxBytesString
          } 
        }
                                        
        let base64EncodedString = channelKey.data(using: .utf8)!.base64EncodedString()
        
        print("base64EncodedString: ", base64EncodedString) // prints “1” as MQ==

    })



MDE= decodes to two characters 01 in ascii (hex 30 31). mQ== decodes to a single character with hex 99. If your incoming value is two ascii digits, you are missing the operation that would squish them into one char with code XY.

When you take the string "01" and convert it to data using .utf8, you're converting the string representation of the number 1 into data, which is indeed "01" in ASCII (or UTF-8 in this case), not the binary value 1 (which in hex is 01).
Try this:
if let intValue = UInt8(channelKey) {
    var data = Data([intValue])
    let base64EncodedString = data.base64EncodedString()

    print("base64EncodedString: ", base64EncodedString)
}


Thank you this really helps and makes more sense! It has slightly different values than expected past the integer 10 "Ch== instead of EA==" but I think I can figure it out or make it work

@nore982 EA== is the base64 encoded version of 0x10 not 10 i.e. 16 in base 10. The encoding of 10 is Cg==, of 11 is Cw== etc.
